# How to refresh automatically global costmap in Rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm wondering how to automatically refresh the global costmap visualization on Rviz. The problem is: I have an initial global costmap and I add an obstacle in gazebo. At this point the global costmap in Rviz should update, but it doesn't. Is there any refresh option? I'm sure that at low level the global costmap is updating since if I disable and then enable the global costmap button, Rviz visualize the new costmap.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191517/how-to-refresh-automatically-global-costmap-in-rviz/) by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-08-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-08-29**:
What topics are you subscribing to? What ROS distro?

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-29**:
I'm subscribing I'm rvizto /move_base/global_costmap/costmap  and I'm using ros hydro in Ubuntu 12.04lts

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-08-29**:
It should be updating then. I'm not sure what the error is.

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-30**:
The error is that in Rviz it's not updating the global costmap but ramains the old one. If I disable and enable angain the costmap in Rviz it visualize. I don't want to do this trick every time but I want that Rviz does it automatically

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2014-09-01**:
The [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) has a parameter called `publish_frequency` (default: 0.0)

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-03**:
yes! There was the default value! I simply changed it to 5.0 and it works! Thanks a lot :)

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-09-03**:
Good call Fernando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) has a parameter called `publish_frequency` (default: 0.0)

---

Originally posted by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) with karma: 738 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4